# ffmpeg hardsubbing ass file into mp4

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4

I am unable to hardsub a subtitle file into a mp4 file. The code that I used (which seems to work once or twice) is:

```
ffmpeg -i "videofile" -vf "ass=assfile" -scodec copy "outputfile"
```

As I understood it, it is a static build. I am using ffmpeg version:

```
ffmpeg version N-70239-g111d79a Copyright (c) 2000-2015
```

and `--enable-libass` appears in the configuration list.

When I add "-v debug" to the command I can see how it's parsing the options, and it seems to be understanding "-scodec copy" somehow:

```
Reading option '-scodec' ... matched as option 'scodec' (force subtitle codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument 'copy'.
```

Does anyone have any idea why is it not working?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the issue is due to the static build that I am using and that as a result of it I need to set some environment variables and have a fonts.conf file. The place that I got my answer was:

https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=318&start=20

The fonts.conf can also be found there.

I set the environment variables to:

```
FC_CONFIG_DIR=C:\Program Files\ffmpeg
FONTCONFIG_FILE=fonts.conf
FONTCONFIG_PATH=C:\Program Files\ffmpeg
```

... in which I basically saved the fonts.conf to root of ffmpeg folder and created new variables.

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:**

Your code has `-scodec` copy. I don't think there is a scodec like `-vcodec` and `acodec`, I think that's your mistake and so try removing it.

**Solution:**

```
ffmpeg -i "videofile" -vf "ass=assfile" "outputfile"
```

**Consider:**

The `ass` filter needs ffmpeg to be compiled with --enable-libass.

Also you must be sure that you are using ass files if not, please convert them to ass using:

```
ffmpeg -i yourSubtitle.srt yourSubtitle.ass
```

Comment: `-scodec`, or the alias `-c:s`, does exist.

Comment: Ok. And do we need it. Because I have hard coded my subtitle a lot of times and never used them.